# VS Code launch.json ignores a change of a default terminal. Why?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, terminal, settings, git-bash

VS Code launch.json ignores a change of a default terminal. Why?

I had the Git Bash as a default terminal. But I was constantly getting the error: `'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` while trying to run: `./node_modules/.bin/mocha`. And if I would run: `node_modules/.bin/mocha` there would be no error.

So, I found out that for this particular project I should use a Windows Powershell. I went over to `>Terminal: Select Default Profile` and picked the `PowerShell`. And now indeed when I head over to the `Terminal` view in VS Code I see the `PowerShell` by default.

But whenever I go over to the `Run and Debug` view and run a `launch.json` configuration it still executes in Git Bash. I tried both restarting only VS Code and my laptop altogether. Still it did not help.

Does VS Code has a separate setting of a default terminal for the `launch.json` execution?

My suspicion is that I need to somehow specify a correct cwd for the Run button (I mean the button which uses the `launch.json` to run the tests). But I can not figure out how I can check the current cwd path and how I can change it. Chaning the `terminal.integrated.cwd` has no effect.

Comment: Hi, just in case, what happens if you add this line to your settings.json: `"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell"`?

Comment: @Laurent, where can I find this `settings.json`? I would like to configure the default terminal for my whole laptop.

Comment: @Laurent, that is what I had in my `settings.json` all this time. So, it does not help. But thank you for trying. (y)